# How to implement Login module as part of my iOS framework

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, frameworks

I am building an iOS framework and it should provide some common module like Register, Forgot Password, Login and Profile etc. So, any application that imports my framework should able to use these screens as it is. The challenge that I am facing is navigating from one screen to another screen in my iOS framework code. When navigating from once screen Login(screen1) to another screen Forgot Password(screen2), the handler(callback) methods are being invoked in screen1 view controller instead of screen2 view controller. We tried using xib and storyboard, however I did not find a solution for this.

Can somebody please point out any example code which does the similar stuff ?

Am I missing some thing over here in understanding iOS concepts, I am building an iOS framework which includes some UI flows, Is it possible?

Comment: Can somebody please help on this ?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/authentication-security/custom-authenticator-login-module/custom-authenticator-login-module-native-ios-applications/) already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a delegate pattern, because callbacks are more one-shot, while delegates serve better the purpose to continually assist the lifetime of an object. Anyway I've created an example to cope with your requirements, git it [here](https://github.com/TeamPacMan/ExampleLoginFramework) (Framework + test app included)

It involves a LoginController, which is the main entry point and orchestra for the framework.

When you initialise it, you pass a callback which will be used to send events, including "forgot password" and "user wants to exit", those are defined in an enum.

```
public enum LoginFrameworkStatus {
    case Login
    case ForgotPassword
    case Help
    case Disaster
    case Exited
    case UserWantsExit
}
```

Class offer an entry point to start the process:

```
public func enterLoginWorkflow(on controller: UIViewController, callback: LoginFrameworkCallback) {
    let myBundle = Bundle(for: LoginController.self)

    if let navi = UIStoryboard(name: "LoginWorkflow", bundle: myBundle).instantiateInitialViewController() as? MySpecialNavigationController {
        presentingController = controller
        navi.loginController = self
        self.callback = callback
        controller.present(navi, animated: true, completion: {
            //presented!
            callback?( .Login, navi, self) //If reference to LoginController is lost, tell the callback there's a problem.. shouldn't happend because we have a strong reference on the navigation controller.
        })
      }   
    }
```

.. and an exit point:

```
public func leaveLoginWorkflow() {
    presentingController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { 
        self.callback?(.Exited, nil,self)
    })
}
```

So the main interface for your framework would be:

```
LoginController().enterLoginWorkflow(on: self) { (status, controller, loginController) in
            print("\(status) in \(controller?.description ?? "No Controller")")

            switch status {
            case .UserWantsExit:
                loginController?.leaveLoginWorkflow()
            case .ForgotPassword:
                loginController?.leaveLoginWorkflow()
            default:
                ()
            }
        }
```

In the test app I included a minimum workflow for you to test.

Let me know if this is what you needed, or if you want to investigate the delegation pattern, which I think would be way more suitable for this.

Comment: I want to earn that bounty so, if there's something grey.. let me know, I can help.

Comment: Hope you got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try 1) IcaliaLabs/LoginKit (https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/LoginKit). LoginKit is a quick and easy way to add a Login/Signup UX to your iOS app.

```
2) TigerWolf/LoginKit https://github.com/TigerWolf/LoginKit
```

Answer (score -1):

We can create a framework just like Parse.com does. It's well known and great app that used by thousands of developers. 
Refer https://github.com/parse-community/ParseUI-iOS